# How could a brown dwarf be used for energy?

Tags: internal-consistency, nuclear-power

I've been thinking about a civilization on a planet orbiting around a brown dwarf drifting in interstellar space. Obviously, by definition, a brown dwarf is too small to have much fusion on its own. I'm thinking about how there could be a way to use the brown dwarf for energy.

A few vague ideas

- Could firing a beam of muons into a brown dwarf cause it to fuse?
- A black hole inside the brown dwarf?
- A fusion reactor which traps gas from the brown dwarf?

Overall, I think having some kind of crumbling space station built in the far past would be best for the story. The dilemma for the society is that they must fix it, leave, or freeze.

Comment: If a civilization evolved on a planet around a brown dwarf then it would almost certainly require the star to provide all the energy to sustain lif on that planet, so it is going to be generating lots of power unless you have some other mechanism inherent to planet itself that generates the required power (needed for life to develop at all).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the level of your civilization - if below Kardashev I (thus comparable to ours), they are not able to undertake any astroengineering projects, such as igniting the brown dwarf, and are limited to exploiting the brown dwarf energy indirectly - much like we are limited to using our Sun.

All depends on how exactly the planet and life developed and where it get the energy from. Note that brown dwarfs can be quite warm (and therefore luminous) - e.g. [Teide 1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teide_1) has the surface temperature around 2600 K and therefore glows quite handily (though solar cell will have hard times) and that could be enough to drive weather on the planet, and then you can directly exploit the weather - especially if the atmosphere superrotates, the (Earth type) civilization will have a lot of abundant wind energy. So much that actually the whole industrial revolution could be based around cheap windmills, not steam & coal. And wind power plants and wind turbines later on.

If, on the other hand, the planet is way past the tiny habitable zone (most likely), it will probably get the energy from tidal heating. Then the life will be based on the "geo"thermal energy, and industry can tap this (volcanoes, warm geysers etc.), and of course, tidal heating implies huge tides - if in the industrial era, predictable and reliable tides could be a base of a lot of electricity production.

The potential use of fossil fuels and nuclear fission is comparable with our civilization and depends on the availability.

In the context of a space station, one possibility is to directly use the (presumably giant) brown dwarf [magnetosphere to generate electricity](https://www-istp.gsfc.nasa.gov/Education/wtether.html).

Comment: The moral of this story: Even if you are not bright at all, you can still be really hot.  And that might be enough!